# PHP Form Checklist show "For:" label instead of "Value:"

Tags: php, forms, checkbox

I finally got a checklist working in PHP, but it's listing the "value:" of my input rather than the "for:" the reason I can't use the 'value:' is because the value is a number that gets totalled up and I want to know what option has been ticked instead of just seeing a number,

```
<input class="basic-config" type="checkbox" name="ch[]" id="basic-option1" value="100"><label for="basic-option1">option 1<span class="right-align">$100</span></label>

<input class="basic-config" type="checkbox" name="ch[]" id="basic-option2" value="200"><label for="basic-option2">option 2<span class="right-align">$200</span></label>
```

The PHP is below:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$name = $_POST ['name'];
$mailFrom = $_POST ['mail'];
$website = $_POST ['website'];
$comments = $_POST ['comments'];
$basicAmount = $_POST ['basic-amount'];
$extras = "None";
if(isset($_POST["ch"]))
$extras = implode(", ", $_POST["ch"]);

$mailTo = "josh@myemail.com";
$headers = "From: ".$mailFrom; 
$txt = "\n
Basic Order Request. \n\n
From: $name \n\n
Email: $mailFrom \n\n
Website: $website \n\n
Comments: $comments \n\n
Extras: $extras \n\n
Total: $basicAmount";
}
```

How can I get it to list the "for" or even "id" name of the checkbox ticked instead of listing the "value"?

**For example, this is what I want:**

Extras: Option 1, Option 2
Total: $300

**This is what I have at the moment and not what I want:**

Extras: 100, 200
Total: $300

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Minor issues not related to your actual problem: You have an extra double quote here `name="ch[]""` and your second checkbox's label is referencing the id of the first checkbox. Your actual problem: PHP does not access form input ids in the manner you'd like.

Comment: Going along with @cteski's comment; you'll likely have to re-factor the convention you're using to assign `name` attributes to your checkboxes to make them accessible in a manner similar to what you're describing. An `input` of `type='checkbox'` with a `name="ch['basic-option1']"` could be accessed like `$_POST['ch']['basic-option1']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only successful controls (inputs) are submitted and only the value.  You can use the option as the array key:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ch[Option 1]" value="100">
<input type="checkbox" name="ch[Option 2]" value="200">
```

Then get those keys:

```
$extras = implode(", ", array_keys($_POST['ch']));
```

Or create a hidden input array and pair them up (use the same key):

```
<input type="hidden" name="ex[0]" value="Option 1">
<input type="checkbox" name="ch[0]" value="100">
<input type="hidden" name="ex[1]" value="Option 2">
<input type="checkbox" name="ch[1]" value="200">
```

Then access the options that have a corresponding check:

```
$extras = implode(", ", array_intersect_key($_POST['ex'], $_POST['ch']));
```

Comment: The first method you have there works perfectly, thanks for your answer!